# Access Denied error when attempting Kinesis stream access across AWS accounts

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis

I am attempting to access a Kinesis stream on one AWS account from a lambda function on another AWS account.  The lambda function attempts to pull data from the AWS account using the Amazon.Kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient class.  I have set up a role on the account with the Kinesis stream (I'll call this the source account) to allow access to the Kinesis stream and to trust a role on the AWS account that contains the lambda function (I'll call this
the sink account).  The role on the sink account allows for the assumption of the role on the source account.  I'm currently receiving the following exception:

```
Amazon.Kinesis.Model.AccessDeniedException: 'User: arn:aws:sts::<account ID>:assumed-role/cross-account-stream-access-role/AWS_SDK_User is not authorized to access this resource'
```

**Role and Policy Setup**

Following diagram shows how the policies and roles are setup between the two accounts:
[image: Role Relationships on Source and Sink Accounts]

The permission and trust relationship policies for the roles on the source and sink accounts are as follows:

Kinesis Access Policy (Source Account):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ReadInputStream",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:DescribeStream",
                "kinesis:GetRecords",
                "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
                "kinesis:ListShards",
                "kinesis:DescribeStreamSummary",
                "kinesis:RegisterStreamConsumer"
            ],
            "Resource": "<Kinesis Stream arn>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust Relationship for Sink Account Role (Source Account):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<ARN for Cross Account Stream Access Role on sink Account>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Source Account Role Assumption Policy (Sink Account):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AssumeRoleInSourceAccount",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "<ARN for Kinesis Access Role on source account>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust Relationship for Lambda AWS Service (Sink Account):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**C# Code**

I am running the following code with an AWS User on the sink account from a lambda function:

```
private static async Task ReadFromKinesisStream(ILambdaContext context)
{
     //create config that points to Kinesis region
    AmazonKinesisConfig config = new AmazonKinesisConfig();
    config.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;

    var secretKey = "<Secret key of user on sink account>";
    var accessKey = "<Access key of user on sink account>";
    var assumeRole = "<arn on Cross Account Stream Access Role on sink Account>";
    var assumedRoleSessionName = "<AWS User name that corresponds to secret key and access key on sink account>";

    BasicAWSCredentials basicAwsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    AssumeRoleAWSCredentials roleAwsCredentials = new AssumeRoleAWSCredentials(basicAwsCredentials, assumeRole, assumedRoleSessionName);
    AmazonKinesisClient client = new AmazonKinesisClient(roleAwsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

    DescribeStreamRequest describeRequest = new DescribeStreamRequest();
    describeRequest.StreamARN = "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:<source account ID>:stream/<Kinesis stream name>";

    DescribeStreamResponse describeResponse = await client.DescribeStreamAsync(describeRequest);
    // Previously mentioned exception occurs on line above.
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
}
```

Myself and another engineer have searched through several tutorials and AWS documents over the past two days and have yet to find any remedies to the previously mentioned exception.

Does anyone know what is incorrect about the AWS role setup or C# code such that I'm receiving this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out what needs to be done in order to allow the IAM user on the sink account to assume the 'Kinesis Access Role' on the source account.  We discovered that we cannot directly assume the 'Kinesis Access Role' on the source AWS account with the credentials of the IAM user on the sink account.  We must programatically have the IAM user assume the 'Cross Account Stream Access Role' on the sink account first.

In the C# code, we must:

1. Create an AWS credentials object for the IAM user on the sink account.
2. Use those credentials to assume the 'Cross Account Stream Access Role' on the sink account through the AssumeRoleAWSCredentials class, which creates credentials for this assumed role.
3. Use the credentials for the 'Cross Account Stream Access Role' to assume the 'Kinesis Access Role' on the source account through the AssumeRoleAWSCredentials class.
4. Use the credentials created for the 'Kinesis Access Role' to create the AmazonKinesisClient.

The corrected code is shown below:

```
    private static async Task ReadFromKinesisStream(ILambdaContext context)
    {
        //create config that points to Kinesis region
        AmazonKinesisConfig config = new AmazonKinesisConfig();
        config.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;

        var secretKey = "<Secret key of user on sink account>";
        var accessKey = "<Access key of user on sink account>";
        var assumeSinkAcctRole = "<arn of Cross Account Stream Access Role on sink account>";
        var assumeSourceAcctRole = "<arn of Kinesis Access Role on source account>";
        var assumedRoleSessionName = "<AWS User name that corresponds to secret key and access key on sink account>";

        BasicAWSCredentials basicAwsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        AssumeRoleAWSCredentials sinkAcctRoleAwsCredentials = new AssumeRoleAWSCredentials(basicAwsCredentials, assumeSinkAcctRole, assumedRoleSessionName);
        AssumeRoleAWSCredentials sourceAcctRoleAwsCredentials = new AssumeRoleAWSCredentials(sinkAcctRoleAwsCredentials, assumeSourceAcctRole, assumedRoleSessionName);
        AmazonKinesisClient client = new AmazonKinesisClient(sourceAcctRoleAwsCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        DescribeStreamRequest describeRequest = new DescribeStreamRequest();
        describeRequest.StreamARN = "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:<source account ID>:stream/<Kinesis stream name>";

        DescribeStreamResponse describeResponse = await client.DescribeStreamAsync(describeRequest);
                                            .
                                            .
                                            .
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinesis does not support cross-account lambda read.  [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-cross-account-kinesis-stream/) is the proposed work-around.

Comment: We realize that a lambda function cannot be _triggered_ by a Kinesis stream in a different AWS account.  However, that is not what we are trying to do, we wish to pull data from a Kinesis stream from a lambda function that is triggered in a different way (ex. CloudWatch Events).  We are using AWS .NET SDK classes to do this, which I think should work.

Comment: I also do not understand why are you entering IAM user `secretKey` and `accessKey` in the lambda code, if the trust is assigned to the lambda execution role, not IAM user

Comment: In the end, we will use an execution role for the lambda function to accomplish this task.  At first we did use an execution role for the function, but we ran into similar errors as the one described above.  During debugging we switched to access and secret keys for the sake of trying a different method for getting role assumption working.